# Animated skillbars on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, animation

In my app I have skillbars which are animated when the website is loaded and everything seems to work. I want to make it animate when I scroll to the skillbars. I am using the library animate.css.

**How can I make this work? What am I missing?**

**skill.js**

```
;(function($) {
  "use strict";

  //skillbars
  $('.progress-back').each(function() {
      $(this).find(
          '.progress-full-line-over').css({
          'width': $(this).attr(
              'data-percent')
      });
  });

})(jQuery);
```

**I have tried to do this but this does not seem to work:**

**skill.js**

```
;(function($) {
  "use strict";

    //skillbars
    $('.progress-back').each(window.onscroll =function() {
        $(this).find(
            '.progress-full-line-over').css({
            'width': $(this).attr(
                'data-percent')
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

**view.html.erb**

```
<div class="progress-wrapper">
  <div class="progress-name">html & php</div>
  <div class="progress-percen">97%</div>
  <div class="progress-back" data-percent="97%">
    <div>
      <div class="progress-full-line-over animated slideInLeft"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="progress-wrapper">
  <div class="progress-name">wordpress</div>
  <div class="progress-percen">80%</div>
  <div class="progress-back" data-percent="80%">
    <div>
      <div class="progress-full-line-over animated slideInLeft"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it with pure CSS only.

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress__box">
    <div class="progress__bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Style

```
.progress {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
}
.progress__box {
    width: 70%; /* bar value */
}
.progress__bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: green;
    -webkit-animation-name: progress; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: progress;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;    
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes progress {
    0%   {width: 0%;}
    100% {width: 100%;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes progress {
    0%   {width: 0%;}
    100% {width: 100%;}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sh14/47xethse/
Animation starts when you scroll to element.